# SQL Server dynamic = operator in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a question about dynamic operators in SQL Server.

As an example,

```
select * 
from table1 
where field_1 = 'ABC'
```

Can we dynamically change the '=' based on parameters? Assume if the above query is in a stored procedure and we have a parameter called `@para`.

My question is:

```
if @para = "x" then the '=' in the above query remains same
if @para = 'y' then '=' should change to '!='
```

Can this be done ?

Query should be something like

```
select * 
from table1 
where field_1 OPERATOR_FIELD 'ABC'
```

There is a reason behind this question. I have a large stored procedure and thought there could be a easy way of changing the operator dynamically than writing `CASE` statement all over the place.

Comment: SP is too long so I am bit reluctant to use dynamic sql for this. I have almost 20 sub queries that use above condition which need to manage simple way..

Answer (score 5):

You could write this as:

```
where ((field_1 = 'ABC' and (@param = '=') ) or
       (field_1 <> 'ABC') and (@param = '<>') )
      )
```

Otherwise you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: bravo! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @para VARCHAR(1) = 'y'
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql =
'SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
    field_1 ' + CASE WHEN @para = 'x' THEN '=' ELSE '!=' END + ' ''ABC'''

PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Another way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE
    (@para = 'x' AND field_1 = 'ABC')
    OR (@para = 'y' AND field_1 != 'ABC')
```

---

Read this [**blog post**](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) by Gail Shaw regarding dynamic search queries.

Here is [**another post**](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0):

First answer is the easiest way
dynamic query is bit complex while debugging

let us change the query in this method

```html
if @para = '=' 
begin 

select * 
from table1 
where field_1 = 'ABC'

end 
else 
begin 
select * 
from table1 
where field_1 <> 'ABC'

end
```